# Avoid Option clash for package xcolor

Tags: pdftex, color

I've looked at other questions about option clash for package xcolor to no avail. Tried putting xcolor before hyperref and tikz, tried adding options [usenames, dvispsnames] to documentclass, and I still get the error.  It also appears to always find the error on line 14, regardless of what is on line 14.

How do I fix this?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, usenames, dvipsnames]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=1.125in, bottom=1.125in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in, footskip=0.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Make the links blue, to follow the Web convention. Using xcolor syntax, internal links will be
% 70 % blue, the remainder black, and URLs 80 % blue (brighter)
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor={blue!70!black}, citecolor={blue!50!black}, urlcolor={blue!80!black}}


\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps}


% Setup Draft watermark %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\tikz[color=red,opacity=0.3]\node{DRAFT};}
\newwatermark*[allpages, angle=45, scale=6, xpos=-20, ypos=15]{\usebox\mybox}


\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: just deleting `\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}` probably does the right thing

Comment: Just using `\usepackage{xcolor}` also works

Comment: Yes, but I need those options in my actual document...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace

```
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

with

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
```

and then let `tikz` load the package.

Or add whichever options `tikz` wants to the options you load `xcolor` with. For example,

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,rgb]{xcolor}
```

Answer (score 7):

This odd behavior is added by package `catoptions`, loaded by `xwatermark`.
Loading a package more than once with different options is not an error in normal LaTeX as long as the first package loading already contains the superset of all options. LaTeX does not load a package file twice (`\newcommand` and other things would not work), but it checks, if there are new options, which are not present at the first loading and throws an error message.

The best workaround seems to be `\PassOptionsToPackage`, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248299/16967) of absent.

Comment: I have written a bug report to the author of package `catoptions`.

Comment: Thanks! There seemed to be a strange interaction in catoptions in one of the iterations I tried that warned about using default options.